# boost asio issue within the loop

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Could someone help me with folowing questions?

1. I'm trying to call async_send within the while loop. The data is sent to server correctly but onSend handler is not called at all... If I do not use the while loop all works fine (the data is sent and received, all handlers ae called)
2. Will my code work correctly if we send some msgs before server's answer on previous msgs?

Here is the TCP client code

```
class TCPClient
{
    public:
        static const size_t maxBufLen = 100;
        static const size_t MAX_INPUT_SIZE = 10;

        TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& IO_Service, tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIter);
        void close();

    private:
        boost::asio::io_service& m_IOService;
        tcp::socket m_Socket;

        char recieveBuffer[maxBufLen];

        void promptTxMsgLoop();
        void onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIter);
        void onReceive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode);
        void onSend(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode);
        void doClose();
};


TCPClient::TCPClient(boost::asio::io_service& IO_Service, tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIter)
: m_IOService(IO_Service), m_Socket(IO_Service)
{
    tcp::endpoint EndPoint = *EndPointIter;
    recieveBuffer[0] = '\0';

    m_Socket.async_connect(EndPoint,
        boost::bind(&TCPClient::onConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++EndPointIter));
}


void TCPClient::onConnect(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode, tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIter)
{
    if (ErrorCode == 0)
    {
        this->promptTxMsgLoop();
    }
    else if (EndPointIter != tcp::resolver::iterator())
    {
        cout << "m_Socket.close();!" << endl;
        m_Socket.close();
        tcp::endpoint EndPoint = *EndPointIter;

        m_Socket.async_connect(EndPoint, 
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::onConnect, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error, ++EndPointIter));
    }
}

void TCPClient::promptTxMsgLoop()
{
    recieveBuffer[0] = '\0';
    while (true)
    {
        cout << "> " ;
        string tmp;
        cin >> tmp;

        cout << "Entered: " << tmp << endl;
        tmp += "\0";

        if (tmp.length() < MAX_INPUT_SIZE-1)
        {
            try
            {
                //lock untill buffer is emty
                while (strlen(recieveBuffer) > 1)
                {

                }
                //onSend handler is never is called inside while loop 
                m_Socket.async_send(boost::asio::buffer(tmp.c_str(),tmp.length()+1),
                    boost::bind(&TCPClient::onSend, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
            }
            catch(exception &e)
            {
                cerr << "Cannot add msg to send queue... " << e.what() << endl;
            }
        }
        else
            cout << "Error: input string is too long. Max length is " << MAX_INPUT_SIZE-1 << endl;
    }
}

void TCPClient::onSend(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
{
    cout << "Msg has been sent..." << endl;

    if (strlen(recieveBuffer) > 1)
        cout << "ERROR: recieveBuffer in not epmty. Data is overritten!" << endl;

    if (!ErrorCode)
    {
        m_Socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(recieveBuffer, TCPClient::maxBufLen),
            boost::bind(&TCPClient::onReceive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "onSend closing" << endl;
        cout << "ERROR! onSend..." << ErrorCode << endl;
        doClose();
    }
}

void TCPClient::onReceive(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
{
    cout << "Msg has been received..." << endl;

    if (ErrorCode == 0)
    {
        cout << recieveBuffer << endl;
        cout << "msg length: " << strlen(recieveBuffer) << endl;

        //unlock buffer
        recieveBuffer[0] = '\0';
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << "ERROR! onReceive..." << ErrorCode << endl;
        doClose();
    }
}

void TCPClient::doClose()
{
    m_Socket.close();
}

int main()
{
    try 
    {
        boost::asio::io_service IO_Service;
        tcp::resolver Resolver(IO_Service);
        tcp::resolver::query Query("127.0.0.1", "1");
        tcp::resolver::iterator EndPointIterator = Resolver.resolve(Query);
        TCPClient Client(IO_Service, EndPointIterator);
        boost::thread ClientThread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &IO_Service));
        ClientThread.join();
        Client.close();
    } 
    catch (exception& e)
    {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }

    cout << "\nClosing";
    getch();

}
```

Comment: Two questions?  Ask them separately.

Comment: Does anything call `run()` or `run_one()` on the associated `io_service`?

Comment: I called `boost::thread ClientThread(boost::bind(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &IO_Service));`

Comment: Do you also call join on that thread? Your question creates more questions. Please consider providing a complete, minimal working example demonstrating your problem. Otherwise... don't expect psychics to give you an adequate answers.

Comment: Of course, I use `join` for client thread

Comment: I updated the question. Please, take a look at this

Comment: The statement `tmp += "\0";` is unnecessary, as the string is terminated properly anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 'onConnect' completion-handler you call `promptTxMsgLoop` that performs an infinite `while` loop, so you actually never let `io_service` to continue its work -- thus no completion handlers will be invoked anymore.

Besides, you call `async_send` multiple times, without waiting for the comletion handler of the previous `async_send`, which is also incorrect.

Please, see asio documentation to find out correct use patterns.